# Arrangement of $4$ girls and $2$ boys sit on a bench

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> $4$ girls and $2$ boys sit on a bench. What is the number of possible
> arrangements if the boys want to stay next to each other?

The solution is $240$, but I got the answer $4! \times 3! = 144$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Treating the boys as a block there'd be $5!=120$ ways to arrange them.  As we have the blocks $B_1B_2$ and $B_2B_1$ we have to double this to $240$.  I suggest editing your post to explain your method.

Comment: Perhaps you have misread boys as girls. Then, your solution is correct.

Comment: Yeah, this is a stupid error! You are right @dodoturkoz